# Object Values Not Updating and Don't Know Why

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor to create accounts and manage their data that looks like this:

```
        function account(fname, lname){
            this.checking = 0;
            this.savings = 0;
            this.total = this.checking + this.savings;
            this.openDate = new Date();
            this.transactions = [];
            this.firstName = fname;
            this.lastName = lname;
            this.deposit = (account, amount) => {
                account += amount;
            };
            this.withdrawal = (account, amount) => {
                account -= amount;
            };
        }
```

...but the problem I'm having is that whenever I try to use the deposit or withdrawal functions the related values aren't updated. I write them out like so:

```
var client = new account("Name", "Name");
client.deposit(client.checking, 5000);
```

...and still no dice. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I have been having IDE issues, but we need to dismiss that as a problem first (using NetBeans).

Comment: A subtle change and it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a6ne2vzh/ You were passing a number into the deposit function; adding to that has no effect on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Strings and numbers are Immutable properties in Javascript and are not modified by reference. You should instead modify the actual object instance value

```js
function account(fname, lname){
    this.checking = 0;
    this.savings = 0;
    this.total = this.checking + this.savings;
    this.openDate = new Date();
    this.transactions = [];
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
    this.deposit = (account, amount) => {
        this[account] += amount;
    };
    this.withdrawal = (account, amount) => {
        this[account] -= amount;
    }
}

var client = new account("Name", "Name");
client.deposit('checking', 5000);
console.log(client);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to do so without having to use bracket notation and strings in the function call but looks like this isn't possible. Also, aren't I affecting the object instance itself by referencing client.checking in the function call?

Comment: client.checking isn't an object, but a number and as I said, numbers and strings are immutable. However if checking was an object like `checking: { amount: 0 }` you would have been able to modify it like `account.amount += amount` as object is mutable

Comment: I getcha. That was a line of reasoning I was thinking before about the number thing because it's drawing it through reference to where the values being added to each other without being assigned can cause an error.